# Did Wonka know where the Golden Tickets were?

Tags: character, willy-wonka-and-chocolate-factory

In the 1970's version of *Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory*, when each child got a Golden Ticket (and later televised announcing it) we see Wilkinson who posed as Slugworth show up to talk to the children about the Everlasting Gobstopper and his deal for them to get it for him (the setup for the final test).

While the other 4 children were shown on TV, there may have been time between them finding/getting the Golden Ticket and Wilkinson, being shown on TV, discussing with them. However Wilkinson was waiting for Charlie shortly after he found the ticket, even though Charlie was told to run straight home.

So did Wonka know approximately where all 5 tickets were? How did Wonka or Wilkinson know the order in which the tickets would be found?

Comment: Related: [How did Willy Wonka know the Golden Tickets would wind up in the hands of children?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60423/12783)

Comment: Just a minor note, this Wilkinson character is not featured in the original book (Slugworth is, albeit by name only and in reference to stealing Wonka's recipes) and so I feel it's just an oversight by the film makers

Answer (score 6):

Wonka controls the tickets, the candy, the shipment. He had everything planned out from the start. By simply staggering the shipment of the golden tickets, he would know when and where they would be found, approximately.

For example: he sends out Ticket 1, in a box headed to Germany. Waits for it to be found. Sends Slugworth. Then he sends out ticket 2. Rinse, lather, repeat.

Comment: I think its first lather, then rinse and repeat...

Comment: @Mennyg Wonka doesn't play by your rules.

Comment: I honestly think Slugworth PLANTED the golden tickets, hence why he was always near by.